# deny direct access to domain

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, referrer

I have several .html files on my server that I want to be able to access only from a certain referrer. If someone comes directly (or from other referrers) to that domain or any file on that server, I want to redirect them to other domain or page.

I could put all of those files in one folder and then call them out with php include, but that is not the best solution, because those .html files are full html pages with javascript.

What could I do here?

Comment: hope you know referrer is browser set, so easy to spoof. if the source pages are yours better to use something like sessions

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in this case, I need super fast loading speed. Won't sessions slow down my pages?

Can I do it with .htaccess?

Comment: ok then whats the problem with putting some code in each, or an include in each file?